# public partial class | var

Tags: c#, xml, var

I'am doing this :

```
var doc = new XPathDocument(Application.StartupPath + "/InfoR.xml");
var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();

var Name = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/name");

var user = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/user");
var PPs = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/PPs");
var aze = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/aze");
```

I'am trying to read those , on the public Partial class . so I can get access to Name , user etc ... from anywhere on my application . (Form1.cs)
but as I can see , can't make var there ... not like int , string , float , ....

Comment: What is the purpose of this? U want to get usersettings from an xml file?

Comment: Let's say I want to get "user" to string , and use it . instead of reading each time ... to get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible the way you are doing it. `var` is for variables local to a *method*, not a *class*. You'll need to declare those variables at the class level as such:

```
private XPathNavigator Name;
private XPathNavigator user;
private XPathNavigator PPs;
private XPathNavigator aze;
```

then in whatever method this is:

```
this.Name = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/name");

this.user = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/user");
this.PPs = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/PPs");
this.aze = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/aze");
```

Then other methods in that class, or its partial friends elsewhere, can access it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are declaring these variables within a method, you will only have access to them within that method.  If you want to use them in other methods in your form, you will need to declare them as member variables.  Something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    XPathNavigator Name;
    XPathNavigator user;
    XPathNavigator PPS;
    XPathNavigator aze;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var doc = new XPathDocument(Application.StartupPath + "/InfoR.xml");
        var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();

        Name = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/name");

        user = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/user");
        PPs = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/PPs");
        aze = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/aze");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question correctly, you are most likely looking for something like this (As example of how to retrieve a node and store it into a property):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(Application.StartupPath + "/InfoR.xml");
        XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
        XPathNavigator node = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/name");
        Name = node.InnerXml;
    }
}
```